# How to insert data to a table in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send data to a table in mysql using php. When I run the following query I don't get any error, but the data is not stored in my table. I can not see my error. Can anyone help me??

```
$connection = new mysqli($db['hostname'],$db['username'],$db['password'],$db['database']);

/*if($connection->connect_errno > 0){
die('Unable to connect to database['.$connection->connect_errno.']');
}*/

$sql_statement="INSERT INTO twitteraccounts('ID','accountName','ConsumerKey','ConsumerSecret','AccessToken','AccessTokenSecret') VALUES
(1,'TestingGerman','costumerKey','costumerSecret','accesToken','accesTokenSecret')";
mysqli_query($connection,$sql_statement);

?>
```

Comment: Who told you to quote column names? And the tutorial that you're following - doesn't it mention to check whether query succeeded or not and print the error if not?

Comment: @N.B. There were similar questions on this site, I just followed one of the solutions.

Comment: And out of all valid and great answers, you managed to find the one that doesn't work.. even though I doubt that, my comment (and answers provided so far) tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @Alexander: that's not the objective of SO, it is the aim to *explain* why something does not work. By simply copying answers, one does not become a better programmer.

Comment: @CommuSoft I totally understand that, before I ask any question I always try my best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get an error because you don't check for one. You should run your query like this

```
if(mysqli_query($connection,$sql_statement))
{
   // ok no errors
}
else
{
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

That will let you know what the error is, then you can fix your query. From the looks of it, the error seems to be the fact that you have column names inside single quotes which is not the right syntax; remove those.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to find the error and fix it because of your advice

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve the error like that :

```
if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql_statement)) {
    printf("Erreur : %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all type of fields.
Ex: if ConsumerKey field is a number you can´t save string.

$sql_statement="INSERT INTO twitteraccounts('ID','accountName','**ConsumerKey**','ConsumerSecret','AccessToken','AccessTokenSecret') VALUES
(1,'TestingGerman','**costumerKey**','costumerSecret','accesToken','accesTokenSecret')";

Regards